# Type constraint

Tags: c#, .net, oop, class, generics

I have the following class hierarchy.

```
class Header { IEnumerable<Item> Item { get; set; } .... }
class HeaderA : Header { .... } // Item should have the type of IEnumerable<ItemA>
class HeaderB : Header { .... } // Item should have the type of IEnumerable<ItemB>

class Item { .... }
class ItemA : Item { .... }
class ItemB : Item { .... }
```

Is it possible to have compile time checking on the type of `Item` to make sure it's `IEnumerable<ItemA>`, `IEnumerable<ItemB>` for `ItemA` and `ItemB` respectively? Is there any better design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the definition of the Header class to pass the type parameter to it, then you could impose that:

```
    class Header<TItem> where TItem : Item { IEnumerable<TItem> Item { get; set; } }
    class HeaderA : Header<ItemA> { } // Item should have the type of IEnumerable<ItemA>
    class HeaderB : Header<ItemB> { } // Item should have the type of IEnumerable<ItemB>

    class Item { }
    class ItemA : Item { }
    class ItemB : Item { }
```

Comment: Would you also consider adding a constraint `where TItem : Item`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Generic Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I thought of using generic. However, `HeaderA` and `HeaderB` add different members.

Comment: see the post of carlosfigueira, you can do that

Comment: got it. I was thinking the design in Darren's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic type and pass it to the class.

```
public class Header<T> where T : Item
{
   IEnumerable<T> Item { get; set; }
}


 Header<ItemA> AHeader;
 Header<ItemB> BHeader;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sz6zd40f(v=vs.100)

Comment: Good approach as well. Do you think a constraint `where T : Item` would be good?

Comment: @Jordão - I've just added that in.  Thanks :-)

Comment: +1 Maybe the OP really doesn't need to create `Header<T>` subclasses if they don't add anything to the base.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
class HeaderA : Header<ItemB> { .... }
class HeaderB : Header<ItemA> { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can change the signatures of the Header class to accomplish this.

```
class Header<ItemType> { IEnumerable<ItemType> Item {get; set;} ....}
class HeaderA : Header<ItemA> { .... }
class HeaderB : Header<ItemB> { .... }

class Item { .... }
class ItemA : Item { .... }
class ItemB : Item { .... }
```

would result in HeaderA only allowing ItemA objects and HeaderB only allowing ItemB objects to be put into their respective Item collections.