# Is it Covariance and Contravariance related issue?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have the following code:

```
class Header<TItem> where TItem : IItem { IEnumerable<TItem> Item { get; set; } }
class HeaderA : Header<ItemA> { public HeaderA(int a) {...} } 
class HeaderB : Header<ItemB> { public HeaderB(int b) {...} } 

interface IItem {...}
class ItemA : IItem { }
class ItemB : IItem { }

public static List<Header<IItem>> list = new List<Header<IItem>> 
{
    new HeaderA(1)
}
```

The compile error on the last `new HeaderA(1)` is

```
Error   1   The best overloaded Add method
'System.Collections.Generic.List<NS.Header<NS.IItem>>.Add(NS.Header<NS.IItem>)'
for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: `new ItemA()` doesn't look like it is called. Do you mean `new HeaderA(1)`?

Comment: @Brad thanks. I've corrected.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to add a `Header<ItemA>` to a `List<Header<IItem>>`. That requires a conversion from `Header<ItemA>` to `Header<IItem>` - and that conversion doesn't exist. It doesn't exist for a good reason. Imagine your code was valid... then this would work:

```
List<Header<IItem>> list = ...; // As per code
Header<IItem> header = list[0];
header.Item = new List<IItem>();
```

Now remember that `header` is *actually* a `HeaderA` - so this working is equivalent to this 
    HeaderA header = new HeaderA();
    header.Item = new List { new ItemB() };

That's not good when anything else would expect `header.Item` to be an `IEnumerable<ItemA>();` - so *this* should be okay:

```
ItemA itemA = header.Item.First();
```

... and clearly won't if you've added an `ItemB` in there.

Basically, you're looking for generic covariance - but you can only declare that on interfaces and delegates (not on classes such as `Header<TItem>`), and only when the type parameter *isn't* used in an input position as it is here due to the `Item` setter.

Perhaps more importantly, your design looks extremely complicated - I *strongly* suspect that if you take a step back, you can design your way around trying to do this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate "take a step back"?

Comment: @NickW: Well, we don't know the bigger picture here - why you've got those types. See if you can accomplish the same bigger goal *without* requiring covariance.

Comment: Originally I have only Header and Item. Later I found that there are other classes which is similar to HeaderA and ItemA and only have a small difference. So Header and Item become HeaderA, HeaderB, ... and ItemA, ItemB, ....

Comment: @NickW: That's not really enough of a context to help, to be honest. I think you're likely to have to try to work this out for yourself.

Comment: Actually the design is about another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410890/type-constraint

Comment: @NickW: Well that's not really a full *design* question - that's just assuming the design you want, and finding out the syntax to do it... I'm suggesting a *wider* redesign.